# What is this white ball growing on my liferock?

Tags: fish, aquarium, saltwater

Today I notices a white ball growing on my a liverock in my aquarium. It only appears on the piece that was previously in my sump, should I be concerned?[image][image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any chance you can take the rock out of the tank for a better picture? Also,  is this a saltwater or freshwater tank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to tell from the picture, but most likely some sort of sponge or tunicate. They typically grow naturally when there is sufficient food and nutrients and with a few exceptions shouldn't be a problem.

Here's a quick guide to common hitchhikers: http://www.xtalworld.com/Aquarium/hitchfaq.htm

Sponges come in just about any color and shape, the most common are ball and pineapple sponges.

Comment: Has the bit of the look of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oikopleura_cophocerca

Comment: @JohnCavan Do you think this is something I should remove or leave?

Comment: Looks like pineapple sponges to me. I would leave them. They're filter feeders and unlikely they are going to be a problem.